# In Haskell, is it possible to provide default implementation for partially applied multi-param type class?

Tags: haskell, default, typeclass, multiparameter

For example, I have a type class :

```
class MyClass a b c where
    fun01 :: a -> b
    fun02 :: a -> c

    fun03 :: a -> b -> c -> ()
    fun04 :: a -> WhatEver
```

I'd like to provide a default implementation for my, let's call it `BaseDataType` which defines implementations of `fun03` in terms of it self and `fun01` and `fun02`. Then I'd have something like this :

```
class MyClass BaseDataType b c where
    fun03 = fun01 <$> fun02 ...
    fun04 = fun02 ...
```

And than to finalize my class instance and avoid all the boilerplate code for `fun03` and `fun04` I'd just provide `fun01` and `fun02` like this :

```
instance MyClass BaseDataType Int Char where
    fun01 = 1
    fun02 = 'C'
```

Is there possibly some language extension that allows this kind of behaviour? I couldn't find anything on this topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such extension, but you can achieve this functionality simply by splitting your class into two classes:

```
class MyClass1 a b c where
    fun03 :: a -> b -> c -> ()
    fun04 :: a -> WhatEver

class MyClass1 a b c => MyClass2 a b c where    
    fun01 :: a -> b
    fun02 :: a -> c
```

Then your instances will work the way you want:

```
-- NB: need the MyClass2 constraint if you use `fun01` or `fun02` in the definitions
-- This requires UndecidableInstances
instance MyClass2 BaseDataType b c => MyClass1 BaseDataType b c where
    fun03 = fun01 <$> fun02 ...
    fun04 = fun02 ...

instance MyClass2 BaseDataType Int Char where
    fun01 = 1
    fun02 = 'C'
```

Users of your class are not affected; they can continue to consume `MyClass2` where they used `MyClass` before and get the exact same functionality.

---

Aside: the original definition of `MyClass`, and `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` don't even compile due to several ambiguous type errors (`c` is not mentioned in the type of `fun01`, etc.) - I assume this class was defined just for demonstration purposes and I haven't tried to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use DefaultSignatures like this

```
class MyClass a b c where
    fun01 :: a -> b
    fun02 :: a -> c

    fun03 :: a -> b -> c -> ()
    default fun03 :: (a ~ BaseDataType) => a -> b -> c -> ()
    fun03 = fun01 <$> fun02 ...

    fun04 :: a -> WhatEver
    default fun04 :: (a ~ BaseDataType) => a -> WhatEver
    fun04 = fun02 ...
```

Comment: +1, but I don't reckon this is usuable for the OP because the default is _for all_ `MyClass` instances, not just for the `MyClass BaseDataType` specialisation. (In other cases, the default implementation will just give a obscure-ish type error to indicate that a custom instance must be replaced.)